# Return true if there are more true booleans than false booleans or if there are the same number of true booleans as false booleans

Tags: javascript

Write a function called `hasMoreTrue` which accepts an array of booleans.

The function should return `true` if there are **more true booleans** than **false booleans** or if there are the **same** number of true booleans as false booleans. Otherwise, the function should return `false`.

How can I compare the number of times an element is true or false in the array length?

```js
function hasMoreTrue(arr) {
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] === true) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
}

console.log(hasMoreTrue([true, true, false])); // true
console.log(hasMoreTrue([true, false, true, false])); // true
console.log(hasMoreTrue([true, false, false, false])); // false
console.log(hasMoreTrue([false])); // false
```

Comment: Have two counters, `trueCount` and `falseCount`, loop through the array, increment the counters appropriately, then `return trueCount >= falseCount`…?

Comment: so now I got: function hasMoreTrue(arr) {
   let trueCount = 0;
   let falseCount = 0;  
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] === true) {
            trueCount;
        } 
        else if (arr[i] === false) {
            falseCount++
        }
    }
    if (trueCount >= falseCount) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
} but it returns everything false

Comment: @Fred_Romer674 `trueCount++;` instead of `trueCount;`.

Comment: nevermind, got it! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The following function filters out the true booleans and check if they are more than half of the array's length i.e more true than false.

```
function hasMoreTrue(arr) {
    return arr.filter((i) => !!i).length >= (arr.length/2);
}
```

Comment: The `!!` isn't necessary in this case. (And the parenthesis around the `i` aren't necessary either.)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use reduce and net counter (c):

```
function hasMoreTrue(arr) {
   return arr.reduce(c, v) => c + (v ? 1 : -1), 0) >= 0;
}
```